# Syncing folders shared by others in Onedrive Business

Tags: permissions, mount, sync, rclone

I've tried to sync a folder shared with me for a while and using different software, but it is just not working.

1. Onedrived

   I don't have the output anymore, but it gave me segmentation faults when syncing. I couldn't even find out how to sync a shared folder.
2. GoodSync

   I forgot what I did but I did not manage to install it properly.
3. rclone

   I followed these instructions: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-mount-onedrive-in-linux-using.html

   This:

   ```
   rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount onedrive: ~/OneDrive
   ```

   creates the folder, but it is inaccessible. Changing the ownership of the config file or the folder from root to user did not work.

   Edit: managed to access the folder, but it still does not find the shared folders and only my personal space.
4. onedrive

   I followed [these instructions at GitHUB](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/Office365.md).

   I tried (with `NAME` changed to all the folder names I could think of):

   ```
   onedrive --get-O365-drive-id 'NAME' --verbose
   ```

   And got:

   ```
   Using Config Dir: /home/nuria/.config/onedrive
   No config file found, using application defaults
   Initializing the OneDrive API ...
   Opening the item database ...
   All operations will be performed in: /home/nuria/OneDrive
   Application version: v2.3.13-18-g27d0b96
   Account Type: business
   Default Drive ID: <ID>
   Default Root ID: <ID>
   Remaining Free Space: 1099490504812
   Fetching details for OneDrive Root
   OneDrive Root exists in the database
   Initializing the Synchronization Engine ...
   Office 365 Library Name Query: NAME
   ERROR: This site could not be found. Please check it's name and your permissions to access the site.
   ```

So far `rclone` or `onedrive` seem to be the best options, but I cannot figure out how to get them to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you re looking for this this information: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/459

The --get-O365-drive-id option is for use with SharePoint Office 365 Libraries - not Business Shared Folders